# How modify CSS of ng-bootstrap carousel using Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

recently, I have tried to modify the class "carousel-item" inside ng-bootstrap carousel component. However, I found that I need to add "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" in the metadata. Using this solution would also change the css on the other carousel component. Is there any other solution to modified the css class inside ng-bootstrap carousel component.

Here is my code:

my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbCarouselConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'carousel',
  templateUrl: 'carousel.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls : ['./carousel.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})

export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
    config.interval = 10;
    config.wrap = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

my View "carousel.component.html":

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=4" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3>
      <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

And my style sheet "carousel.component.scss":

```
  .carousel-item.active{
    display:inline;
    img{
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has more to do with how styles encapsulation work in Angular rather than something specific to [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io), but the short answer is that in the default style encapsulation (from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html):

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template

Since [ngb-carousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel) is *not* part of the component HTML (it is a different component altogether) you have to force styles to propagate down the components structure:

> Use the /deep/ selector to force a style down through the child
>   component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ selector
>   works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the
>   view children and content children of the component

Translating this to your particular problem would mean that you should write:

```
  styles: [`
     /deep/ .carousel-item.active {
        border: solid 0.3em;
        border-color: red;
     }
  `]
```

Here is a live example in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7J3CItUtSua1zJ7GG1xH?p=preview

Comment: `::ng-deep` is now recommended over `/deep/`

Comment: ::ng-deep is now deprecated, any other alternatives for this?