# Overwrite component HTML/add or remove css on third party components

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the ng-carousel https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts and I want to have different prev/next icons. I'm interested in using the font-awesome ones as opposed to the ones that are there by default. Is it possible to change the template css classes that are used somehow or do I have to extend that component and write my own template (like suggested here [Angular2: How to override components template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666510/angular2-how-to-override-components-template))?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Perhaps I need to rephrase the question:

I'd like to do the equivalent of changing/swapping CSS classes:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  /* extend FontAwesome left chevron*/
  @extend .fa-chevron-left;
}
```

but I'm not using Sass.

Comment: What code have you attempted? what were your results?

Comment: Has your question anything with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610229/how-modify-css-of-ng-bootstrap-carousel-using-angular-2)?

Comment: Its totally possible, but without seeing any code its not possible to tell you how to do it in your case.

Comment: It's very related to the this issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21985 --> basically the solution offered by using Sass where you can replace classes with other classes is what I wanted using @extend but I have plain css, that's why I didn't know whether you can "easily" add to a third party component element without too much hassle / dirtiness. I thought of inheriting from that class and attach my custom template to it but I'm not sure if that's the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this official documentation part on CSS special selectors : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors

You should be able to change the CSS using special selector (such as /deep/) to customize it to your own tastes.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged as links can become obsolete over time. Please include the relevant sections of the linked page in your answer.